# AppendTo previous iteration (each)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code, which should split this string `@266@@271@@295@` into this

```
<a href="#">266</a>
<a href="#">271</a>
<a href="#">295</a>
```

and append it to the same container where it came from: `.groups`

```
$('.groups').each(function(){
    var str = $(this).html();
    if (str.substring(0, 1) == '@') {
        str = str.substring(1); // Remove first @
    }    

    if(str.substring(str.length-1,  str.length) == '@'){
        str = str.substring(0, str.length-1); // Remove last @
    }

    str = str.split(/[@@]+/);

    $(this).empty(); // empty the groups container

    $.each(str, function(index, val){
        alert(val);
        var html = '<a href="#">' + val + '</a>'
        $(html).appendTo(this);
    });
});
```

My problem (i think) is the line `$(html).appendTo(this);`
i somehow need to add it to the previous `each()`.

How can I do this. Or am I moving in the wrong direction with this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you made this way too complicated, just do this:

```
var str = $(this).html();
var parts = str.split("@");

var html = "";
for (var i = 0; i < parts.length; i++) {
    html += '<a href="#">' + parts[i] + '</a>';
}

$(this).append(html);
```

Comment: Okay - I really did make it too complicated! Thank you so much - worked like a charm. But I still needed to use `.empty()`

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
$('.groups').each(function(){
    var str = $(this).html();
    if (str.substring(0, 1) == '@') {
        str = str.substring(1); // Remove first @
    }    

    if(str.substring(str.length-1,  str.length) == '@'){
        str = str.substring(0, str.length-1); // Remove last @
    }

    str = str.split(/[@@]+/);

    $(this).empty(); // empty the groups container

    var target = $(this);

    $.each(str, function(index, val){
        alert(val);
        var html = '<a href="#">' + val + '</a>'
        $(html).appendTo(target);
    });
});
```

I added the `var target = $(this)` outside your second loop as a reference that you can use inside your second loop.

Answer (score 0):

You do need to be mindful of the leading and trailing @'s, but you can easily trim them while you split with a clever regex.  When you use $.each to iterate over an array, the **this** reference no longer refers to your original context but to the current item.  Constructing the item's markup and concatenating to a string which you insert outside of the loop will not only get around this, but also provide better performance since you will only be doing one DOM insertion.

```
$('.groups').each(function(){
    var str = $(this).html();
    str = str.replace(/^@+|@+$/g, ''); // trim leading and trailing @
    var links = str.split("@");

    var markup = '';
    $.each(links, function(){
        markup += '<a href="#">' + this + "</a>\n";
    });

    $(markup).appendTo(this);
});
```

Comment: Thank you for a better understanding of regex Leonardo